# How to send a mail with only Summary report listener's Total columns

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way where i trigger a jmeter job from jenkins for 100 threads and once the test is done the result with below details

Total Sample - 100
Average - 324
Min - 200
Max - 500
Throughput 4536
Sent bytes - 843
Received bytes - 643

Above result is the result of all the threads.

Are saved in a html or .csv file in a path and jenkins picks the .html or .csv result and publish the result through mail to set of people ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .csv file with the required information using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv result.csv --input-jtl result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

You can install JMeterPluginsCMD tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Command Line Tools]

---

Once done you can [Archive Arficacts](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/) (the `result.csv` file) to your build dashboard so it will be available for all Jenkins users. If you want to send it via email - go for [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)